# Different tab/space policy for different Eclipse Java projects

Tags: java, eclipse, indentation

I have my own projects which I like to see indented with tabs. I also downloaded a third party project which uses spaces, and I want to customize it. I want to preserve the coding style of the third party lib, but I still want to use my favorite one tab = one depth style for the projects that are entirely my own.

I browsed through many Eclipse setting, but I still cannot see my way out. I'm using Eclipse Juno SR1 with Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easily done. In **Windows > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter** you can define the various formatters you'd like to use.

Then, each project can be adjusted to use a different one, by right-clicking on the project and adjusting the preferences there.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for posting not an answer, but this seemed really appropriate... ;)

[image: Tabs or spaces]
<sub>(source: [emacswiki.org](http://www.emacswiki.org/pics/static/TabsSpacesBoth.png))</sub>

Comment: EPIC! :D Thank you! Copyleft?

Answer (score 2):

Go to "properties" on an eclipse project, then find "Java Code Style" -> "Formatter" and set it us project specific settings. There you can define the formatter properties for the project .